# cannot browse Eclipse-deployed Spring webapp in Tomcat (using OSX 10.8)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I've used these 2 guides to install/configure eclipse and Tomcat.

http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/tomcat7

http://www.banym.de/eclipse/install-tomcat-with-eclipse

I can start Tomcat via the server tab in Eclipse. But when I try to browse my webapp, I can't see it in the browser. I looked into the deployed folder and my webapp is there. I even created a hello.jsp inside it and I'm getting a 404 HTTP error when I try to view it.

Here's a screenshot of my Eclipse configured to use tomcat. It also shows the deployed directory and the hello.jsp file I created.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK9Uk.jpg

Here's a screenshot of my browser not being able to see hello.jsp.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJGSo.jpg

I created another hello.jsp and put this in the $TOMCAT_INSTALL_FOLDER/webapps/ROOT and I can see it on my browser.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks

ps. Here's the console eclipse output when I start tomcat. There is a warning somewhere at the top but reading another discussion here in stackoverflow, supposedly I can ignore it.

```
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/vill0042/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:directory' did not find a matching property.
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 868 ms
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [144] milliseconds.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/docs
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/examples
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@25c5738d')
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/host-manager
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/manager
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 12, 2013 2:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8157 ms
```

Comment: Can occur beacause of two possible reasons. Firstly, please ensure you have a `web.xml` in your application. Secondly,try changing the folder of your deployment. Check if you application works with something like a `XYZ` folder in `webapps`. Use the appropriate folder path as a hyperlink to access it.

Comment: What is your project structure? You are using spring, what is `DispatcherServlet` mapping? Are you sure you can access `jsp`s?